# QGIS freezing/crashing

Tags: qgis

I recently installed QGIS version 2.18.28 on my workstation, but it keeps crashing/freezing. There isn't much data in it at all. Sometimes it even crashes when there isn't any data at all, and just one OSM layer for example. There is not a specific command that causes the problem. 
I tried version 3.4 but that's just as bad. My workstation is a MSI WT72, it was pretty expensive and it should be powerfull enough to handle QGIS I hope. Autodesk Recap, infraworks and Civil3D isn't a problem at all. 
I already tried to reinstall my graphic card drivers, and changed the settings from Auto selection to NVIDIA quadro 3000M without any results. 
What else can I try?

Comment: Are you installing plugins for QGIS? If yes, wich ones?

Comment: Not too many, only the standard plugins, quickmapservices and OSM downloader. I can try to turn off a few plugins.

Comment: Now i have an example; I have a csv file with 5 coordinates, only two colums with X and Y coordinates. I add a new csv layer, and the map freezes. There is only 1 other layer, the OSM cylist map. The buttons on top aren't frozen, so I can save the file and close QGIS. When I open the saved project the coordinates are in the project and it looks like nothing happened,  till I want to do something else. like adding more coordinates.

Comment: Can you remove `C:\Users\YourUser\AppData\Roaming and Local\QGIS` folders and start again with a clean profile, in just one version of QGIS?

Comment: I removed the folders you mentioned, and tried but no results. I also tried to uninstall and install QGIS over new but it still isn't working. Very annoying, why can't I run this programm while all other programms run without any problems??

Comment: I don't know. QGIS 2.18 reaches its end of life, but I keep an installation of `2.18.28-3` because it is impressively stable. I'm assuming you download the installers from the official site of QGIS. Did you try with the OSGeo4W network installer?

Comment: I tried with the OSGe04W installer as well, and got the downloads from the original site. I tried version 3 as well, but that version is even worse on my computer.

Comment: What is the result when you load a csv layer. Can not you zoom the map? I am not understanding at all what you mean with "freezes".

Comment: It is not only with importing csv layers. With some commands or zooming I can't see in the map what has happened, and the coordinates and scale aren't changing. I can use the buttons on the upper bar and can save my project for example, while I can't pan, zoom or do anything in the map. When I save the project, close the project and re-open it I can see that QGIS did save the changes while it was 'frozen'.

Comment: But it is not a QGIS specifically related issue. It is related to a plugin, or to the data, or to the environment. You can try with the same data and same plugins in a virtual machine to check the environment. Or in the same environmet and data but without plugins to check them. If you can reproduce the issue without plugins in any anvironment, share the data that is ocasionating the issue.